# What's up with this Anunnaki question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Who were the Anunnaki according to Sumerians' tales?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/172/who-were-the-anunnaki-according-to-sumerians-tales) has been closed, re-opened, edited a lot over its life, and now has two close votes on it. It has been criticized as unclear, focusing on pseudoscience, and too broad. I suggest that, rather than have another mini debate over it, we discuss it in meta.

- What are its problems? Is it too broad, or off-topic?
- What are its strengths? Is it narrow enough, though not too narrow?

A second option is to do nothing and let the question be closed or stay open, but I think we should talk this one over.

Answer (score 6):

Seen the comments and the edit history, this question started asking about "Ancient Aliens/extraterrestrial race in Sumerian myth" and then became something more in the main tone of the site. This explains why it has VTCed and VTRed (after edits).

Unfortunately, as it is, I think that could be answered via Google (I may be wrong and may be much more to this question than that), which does not contribute to think the question shows research effort. In spite of that, as it is right now I think it deserves to be kept over. Seems to be on-topic.

I won't say that is too broad either, or that its multiple questions should be asked separately.

Comment: I thought one of the purposes of Stack Exchange was to provide authoritative, Google-able answers to questions. Does it matter that you can read a Wikipedia article on them? We should give that short answer and then add some more, no?